# Javascript - Can't get postion of cursor on Touchend event

Tags: javascript

im trying to create a small script for simulating a swipe on a web page, here is the code :

```
   var startX;
   var endX;

   document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
     console.log(startX);
   }, false);

   document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    endX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    console.log(endX);
   });
```

But when im swiping on the browser it says >TypeError: e.targetTouches[0] is undefined

I tried to only display the event with :
`console.log(e);` 
and it seems there is no position for the touchend event.

I need help please :(

Comment: `touchend` events do not have `targetTouches`. You'll find what you want in the `changedTouches` property

Comment: i got this error:  `e.changedTouches[0] is undefined` because the changedTouches contains nothing on the touchend event